# How to duplicate objects with constraints using script?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a few objects which are connected. This code copies without constraints. How should I modify it for duplicating ALL things on the scene?

```
import bpy
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    ob.select
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
```

Comment: What do you mean "without constraints" and "are connected"? Why would you want to do this in python anyway? (you could just select everything, then duplicate)

Comment: I need script which should create many copies of linked objects because doing it in another way isn't fast.

Comment: I need script which should create many copies of linked objects because doing it in another way isn't fast.  It's just an [example](http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=a301df3e15a490b81615a414d6a2e494). And if I use correct code (as below) constraint isn't duplicate. How can I select it?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Does that fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a python script that will duplicate all objects in the current scene:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.select = True

# use this to duplicate without links
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()

# use this to duplicate with links
bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move_linked()
```

A few things to note about your code:

1. obj.select is just a variable...you know this because it doesn't have the parentheses.
2. You would have been recursively duplicating because that call was inside of your `for` loop.